# OpenLayers ArcGIS Image Service Support

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, rest, arcgis-image-server

i have ArcGIS Image Server for publishing my raster data to my user. In traditionally way i have been tiling with gdal and it takes a long time besides this it requires more effort for getting true result.

Do you know ArcGIS Image Service support for openlayers like Openlayers ArcGIS Server REST support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of adding the [USGS national map that is hosted on an ArcGIS Server via REST](http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/Orthoimagery/USGS_EDC_Ortho_HRO/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS) to OpenLayers as a WMS layer.

[USGS WMS Layer Link](http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/Combined)

[image]

**[HERE's the DEMO](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/arcgis.htm)**

Make sure the data is published using ImageServer:

- [Tutorial 1](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About%20serving%20raster%20data)
- [Tutorial 2](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#tutorial_img_svc_iscdef.htm)

[image]

Comment: thank you. it is what i want. but there is a misunderstanding. in your answer, you say that i have to use [this](http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/Combined/USGS_EDC_Ortho_NAIP/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS), but in your demo link you have added [this](http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/Combined/SDDS_Imagery/MapServer/WMSServer). pls make me clear which service should i use?

Comment: hi, i have published my image service under mapserver as your example, but problem is that my spatial reference is esri:54004 and i dont know is it problem or not but i didnt get raster image on openlayers....

Comment: I see, you're right. I could have sworn I used the image server on that one... ohh well, we'll go off what my working demo is using like you're doing. Is your ArcGIS Service URL public? Is it possible you can share it so we can test it?

Comment: Excellent, I assume you got it working. :)

Comment: sorry CaptDragon, my company is working on local network...and now i have achieved  to add image service to openlayers. i have only changed esri:54004 to 54004 with adding proj4 to my code... it is a bit of slow but works good... thank you again. you really deserve this bounty.. :)

Comment: The current link no longer works, so this response is no longer valid. Please, don't use external resources to show a response.