# Using OpenLayers to work with REST from ArcGIS ImageServer

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, openlayers-2, arcgis-image-server

I already have ArcGIS Image Server for publishing raster data to my users. I have a third party application that will allow me to add a custom web map as a base layer using OpenLayers2.

I have found endless examples of ArcGIS REST MapServer and WMS services being used with OpenLayers but nothing for Image Server.

Does anyone know ArcGIS REST Image Server support for Openlayers 2 and how to achieve using a REST Image Server with OpenLayers?

Comment: Why do you have openlayers-3 tag when it's about 2?

Comment: sorry i didnt notice the 3, i have ammended my tags.

Comment: 1. Assume its not a tiled image service?  2. Assume you have not enabled the WMS capability on the image service?

Comment: Related Question - not a duplicate unless it answers your question, and if it does, please answer your question.
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21920/openlayers-arcgis-image-service-support

Comment: Its not a tiled image service and i have not enabled WMS capability on the image service.

That question may have answered my question but the links are all broken so I have no clue as to what he had setup or coded for Openlayers.... :(

Comment: If I had WMS turned on for the image service how would I use OpenLayers2 for ArcGIS REST WMS?